# docker для чайника

Tags: docker

Поставил я docker и docker-compose на Win10, сделал три контейнера с nginx, php, mysql. Все работает, но не понятно как так.

К примеру, я захожу через `docker exec -it` в контейнер c nginx, и там по факту у меня убунту стоит и я могу ставить там что хочу... Откуда она там взялась, почему при скачивании ее не было. Как так это происходит

Кто может мне объяснить как это работает. Перечитал тонны материала, но никак не пойму. Мне бы простым языком как для дурака

Comment: 1. непонятно, что именно вам непонятно. 2. *там по факту у меня убунту стоит* — как вы это узнали? 3. *сделал три контейнера* — как именно?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin не понятно почему есть командная строка, почему я могу сделать какой нибудь apt install и тд, хотя там же только nginx должен быть к примеру. Сделал через docker-compose

Comment: 1. потому что есть программа, выполняющая функции оболочки. скорее всего, *bash*. 2. потому что есть программа *apt*. 3. там должно быть то, что вы указали при создании образа. 4. вы так ни слова и не сказали, как именно создавали образы.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin брал готовые типа nginx:latest и потом просто дописал конфиги на nginx и основной конфиг в docker-compose.yml. ничего дополнительно не собирал сам

Comment: Во-первых, не убунту, а дебиан. Во-вторых, образ nginx базируется на дебиане, а в дебиане всегда был apt, вот и всё

Comment: @andreymal тоже самое и с php и mysql получается?

Comment: @PaulWall да, у всех троих в докерфайлах прописано debian:stretch-slim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> брал готовые типа nginx:latest и потом просто дописал конфиги на nginx и основной конфиг в docker-compose.yml. ничего дополнительно не собирал сам

если «брали» с докерхаба, то, значит отсюда: https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx

а там тег latest ведёт вот на такой [dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/e5123eea0d29c8d13df17d782f15679458ff899e/mainline/stretch/Dockerfile):

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim
...
```

т.е., образ `nginx:latest` строится на основе `debian:stretch-slim` (см. [debian](https://hub.docker.com/_/debian)).

отсюда и наличие программы `/usr/bin/apt`.

---

ну а по поводу программы, выполняющей функции оболочки (`/bin/sh`, `/bin/bash` и т.д. и т.п.): да, технически docker-образ без какой-либо оболочки собрать можно. вот только очень многие программы (внутри такого образа) не смогут после этого (нормально) функционировать.